# ORA-00923 from keyword not found when trying to do a join

Tags: sql, join

When I previously ran this code for a join:

```
SELECT 
    Outlet.Address, Outlet.ManagerNumber, 
    Department.DepartmentName, Department.FloorArea
FROM
    Outlet
INNER JOIN 
    Department ON Outlet.OutletNumber = Department.OutletNumber;
```

It worked. However, I am trying to run a similar join it simply does not work:

```
SELECT
    Product.Description Product.Price,
    ProductAtOutlet.Quantity,
    ProductAtOutlet.OutletNumber
FROM
    Product
INNER JOIN 
    ProductAtOutlet ON Product.ProductNumber = ProductAtOutlet.ProductNumber;
```

And I keep getting the error message

> ORA-00923 from keyword not found

Answer (score 1):

missing comma, after description?

```
SELECT
    Product.Description,
    Product.Price,
    ProductAtOutlet.Quantity,
    ProductAtOutlet.OutletNumber
FROM
    Product
    INNER JOIN ProductAtOutlet ON Product.ProductNumber = ProductAtOutlet.ProductNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are missing a comma after `Product.Description`.  This causes the parser to see `Product.Price` as a column alias.  Having a `.` in an unquoted alias results in a parser error.